# How can I enable and disable specific date in php on demand?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I want to enable particular dates and disable it after completing task.I dont know how to start and what to do first.Please suggest me.

"02-03-2016","19-03-2016","23-03-2016",

Comment: Pretty Unclear. Please elaborate your question and your needs

Comment: Initially current date is enable. But for some task i want to enable previous some dates and after completing that task only current date is enable.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit hard to understand your needs but I guess that you are using datepicker and you want to disable and renable some particular dates.

You do it by using `beforeShowDay` while you instantiate your datepicker. Before to respond your question, let's start by reminding what the beforeShowDate does:

> A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
>
> ```
> [0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
> [1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation
> [2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
> ```
>
> The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is
>   displayed.

So to disable a specific date you need to return `[false]` in the function `beforeShowDate` when you have in parameteter the date you want to disable and `[true]`  if not. So I urge you to use a global variable `dateDisabledArray` where you put all the date you want to disable. So here's a small code where I disable these dates : "2016-03-11","2016-03-02" and "2016-03-24":

```
var dateDisabledArray = ["2016-03-11","2016-03-02","2016-03-24"];
$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ dateDisabledArray.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

Now if you want to renable the previous dates, you only have to do :

```
dateDisabledArray = [];
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxNNh/2897/) where I disable these dates on a click and renable them in the folowing click.

Comment: Today current date is 25th march. so my previous dates were disabled. but for some task i have to enable some dates on demand.And in your example  dates are disabled and i want them to be enable.

Comment: My example just showed you how to disable dates. Now all you need to do is to change the variable `array` in the example and put on it all the dates that you want to disable.

Comment: I don't want to disable date.My calander dates are already disabled.and i want to enable particular date from that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand well your question before. Look at my edit, you will find all you need